# Excel Sum inside Vlookup Hor

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I need to sum/combine from a vlookup (or some other method, if there is a better one)

Here is the data:

`J#     Hours
16148  3
16067  4
16148  10`

Currently, I use this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F6,'Time Sheet'!$B$23:$F$28,5,FALSE),"")
```

This pulls data from one sheet, then sorts it out based on the j#. Problem is, I need to combine entries. Id like to add a sum component, but after a couple of hours messing and searching. I have had no luck.

Can someone point me in the direction of an answer? I don't even know if I am close.

Sorry if I don't provide enough information. I will answer whatever questions and edit my post accordingly if I forgot anything.

Update #1
Okay, so I have tried the sumif, and I have had some success. The problem I had orginally and why I avoided the use of sumif, is that my table contains blank cells and this causes those records to be counted when they shouldnt. I will spend some time seeing if I cant sort that out.

Comment: So you want to *sum up* the entries that match your lookup? Something like `SumIf`?

Comment: Yes. If you could get me some guide as to how I can impliment that. That would be great. I did try using Sum and Sumif. To no avail. Then again, I am not that familiar with Sumif and I might have done it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can use `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF('Time Sheet'!$B$23:$B$28, $F6, 'Time Sheet'!$F$23:$F$28)
```

It will find all matches of `$F6` in the column `'Time Sheet'!$B$23:$B$28` and sum the corresponding values in column `F`.

Comment: Not sure if I am implimenting this wrong. Do I need to wrap this inside of the Vlookup? I am getting a return of 0 for my answer.

Comment: No, just like that. But maybe you need to make sure that the data correctly matches. The abive formula takes criteria from cell `F6` and looks for matches only in 6 cells (from row 23 to row 28). Maybe you want to extend the check for the whole column `F`?If so try `=SUMIF('Time Sheet'!B:B, $F6, 'Time Sheet'!F:F)`

Comment: Well I need the Vlookup, because I am referencing other data. So I am not sure how this would work. I use this to look up all records in the range B23:F28 which match the J#. Now I want it to find multiple records in there, and sum the hours. Does that make sense?

Comment: @FrankEdgar `VLookup` is not designed to find multiple records; just the first one. `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` are designed to accumulate multiple matches. The above accumulates the numbers from column `F` for matches found in column `B`. We can tweak it but I need to know what are the columns that you want to sum up. Please try to edit your question with some more details.

Comment: I selected your answer as the correct one Thank you.

Comment: @FrankEdgar you are welcome, I hope it gave you a good track to complete your code. I keep ready to help for any further issue.